# PostgreSQL average for every field

Tags: sql, postgresql, math

I'm trying to calculate the average in this sample; This example **is working** (but only when I select a specific ID, rather than the avg for every ID limited to 20 entries) but I'm having a hard time remembering how to calculate this for every **id** within the database, rather than the developer specifying the ID explicitly (in this case as **2958**). I.E. It would be optimal to have the following rows (assuming this is grouped by each primary key with a limit of 20 values per avg):

- ID: 1 -> avg 5
- ID: 2 -> avg 2
- ID: 3 -> avg 7
- etc....

  ```
  select avg(acc.amt) 
  from (
      select acc.amt amt
      from main_acc main_acc
        join transactions trans on main_acc.id = trans.main_acc_id
      where main_acc.id = 2958
      order by main_acc.track_id, transactions.transaction_time desc 
      limit 20
  ) acc;
  ```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. The only relevant columns are the ones shown above, I can add a schema definition if requested. Thank you!

Comment: use GROUP BY clause on the ID

Answer (score 0):

```
select main_acc.id, avg(acc.amt) from (select acc.amt amt
    from main_acc main_acc
             join transactions trans on main_acc.id = trans.main_acc_id
    
    order by main_acc.track_id, transactions.transaction_time desc) acc
group by main_acc.id;
```

In fact you do not need the subquery.

```
select acc.id, avg(acc.amt)
    from main_acc acc
             join transactions trans on acc.id = trans.main_acc_id
group by acc.id
```

Comment: Thanks @tarik, I think this is a great leap from where I was. I've edited the orignal post to reflect the "limit of 20" I mentioned, is this a possible addition? I've tried to implement it myself but keep having issues. The problem is there are thousands of entries, and I only want the average of the most recent 20, so that's why im trying to implement the limit 20.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then revert to the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define *most recent*. Is there a timestamp which is not shown, do you use the greatest id, something else? Basically, you order by that criteria and then use limit. So expanding the answer from @Tarik and assuming highest ids as most recent would yield something like:

```
select acc.id, avg(acc.amt) avg_for_id
    from main_acc acc
             join transactions trans on acc.id = trans.main_acc_id
group by acc.id
order by acc.id desc
limit 20;
```

Comment: I'm using the order by desc for transaction_time to determine the most recent, which is why I was looking to use the order by to get the most recent 20 entries